# Getting 'Can only use .str accessor with string values!' error when there are no records to processed in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like

```
df_merge_filtered=dfmerge[['category','title','body','start','end','relatedEntities.id','location.position.lat','location.position.lon']]

riskc=df_merge_filtered['category'].str.split(',', expand=True).melt()['value']\
          .str.split(':', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Level1', 1:'Level2'})
```

This code breaks when  I have 0 records in df_merge_filtered dataframe.

**Error**

```
Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I want to create dummy dataframe structure even if there no records to be processed.

How to fix this

Comment: Your code needs values in order to be able to work. What exactly to you expect `riskc` to contain if `df_merge_filtered` is an empty dataframe?

Comment: @DeepSpace, Just two columns` ['Level1','Level2']`

Answer (score 0):

With no rows of data the `melt` call and `['value']` reference have a default `float64` empty column. You can force this back to a string column so the code runs, but without the `:` to split on we still don't get the right result.

```
In[] df_merge_filtered = pd.DataFrame(columns=['category','title','body','start','end','relatedEntities.id','location.position.lat','location.position.lon'])
In[] df_merge_filtered['category'].str.split(',', expand=True).melt()['value']
Out[]: Series([], Name: value, dtype: float64) # float64 dtype on empty result!
```

If we force the string datatype then expanding on `:` will give a 0 row DataFrame. The rename will *optionally* rename the 2 columns you want but there's nothing to rename:

```
df_merge_filtered['category'].str.split(',', expand=True).melt() \
['value'].astype('string') \
.str.split(':', expand=True)
#.rename(columns={0:'Level1', 1:'Level2'})
Out[]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Maybe you could detect the 0-row case and handle it separately?

```
if df_merge_filtered.shape[0] == 0:
    riskc = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Level1', 'Level2'])
else:
    # original code
```

I'll ask as a sanity check - do you know that you only ever have the same number of commas (else you'll have missing values after the first `split`) and only one colon per item (else you'll have multiple columns with missing items after the second `split`)?